# Assigning name to rows in R

Tags: r, row

I would like to assign names to rows in R but so far I have only found ways to assign names to columns. My data is in two columns where the first column (geo) is assigned with the name of the specific location I'm investigating and the second column (skada) is the observed value at that specific location. To clarify, I want to be able to assign names for every location instead of just having them all in one .txt file so that the data is easier to work with. Anyone with more experience than me that knows how to handle this in R?[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import the data to your global environment. Try the function `read.table()`

To name rows, try
(assuming your data.frame is named `df`):

```
rownames(df) <- df[, "geo"]
df <- df[, -1]
```

Comment: When i run
`rownames(raps_geo_skada) <- raps_geo_skada[, "raps"]
raps_geo_skada <- raps_geo_skada[, -1]`

I get an error message saying

"Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘M120m’, ‘M1Kant’, ‘M220m’, ‘M2Kant’, ‘NO120m’, ‘NO1Kant’, ‘NO220m’, ‘NO2Kant’, ‘NV120m’, ‘NV1Kant’, ‘NV220m’, ‘NV2Kant’, ‘SO120m’, ‘SO1Kant’, ‘SO220m’, ‘SO2Kant’, ‘SV120m’, ‘SV1Kant’, ‘SV220m’, ‘SV2Kant’ "

Does this simply mean I can't have ex. multiple "M120m" in the row?

Comment: @AxelRösvik Yes, thats correct. In a data.frame you must use unique rownames. See `df <- data.frame(1:3)` `rownames(df) <- c("a", "a", "b")`. However, if your whole data set is e.g. numeric values you could save your data in a matrix instead and have non unique rownames. See `mat <- as.matrix(df)` `rownames(mat) <- c("a", "a", "b")`

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is not that clear...

I assume you are trying to create a `data.frame` with named rows. If you look at the `data.frame` help you can see the parameter `row.names` description

> NULL or a single integer or character string specifying a column to be used as row names, or a character or integer vector giving the row names for the data frame.

which means you can manually specify the row names when you create the `data.frame` or the column containing the names. The former can be achived as follows

```
d = data.frame(x=rnorm(10), # 10 random data normally distributed
               y=rnorm(10), # 10 random data normally distributed
               row.names=letters[1:10] # take the first 10 letters and use them as row header
               )
```

while the latter  is

```
d = data.frame(x=rnorm(10), # 10 random data normally distributed
               y=rnorm(10), # 10 random data normally distributed
               r=letters[1:10], # take the first 10 letters
               row.names=3 # the column with the row headers is the 3rd
)
```

---

If you are reading the data from a file I will assume you are using the command `read.table`. Many of its parameters are the same of `data.frame`, in particular you will find that the `row.headers` parameter works the same way:

> a vector of row names. This can be a vector giving the actual row names, or a single number giving the column of the table which contains the row names, or character string giving the name of the table column containing the row names.

---

Finally, if you have already read the `data.frame` and you want to change the row names, Pierre's answer is your solution